# Razorpay offers missing on checkout

Tags: laravel, razorpay

I had integrated Razorpay in web application using javascript, I want to display offers list which are added from dashboard.

Referred following link to integrate offers https://razorpay.com/docs/offers/integration/

Here is java script code

> ```
> var options = {
>   "key": "Key",
>   "amount": "10000",
>   "name": "CodesCompanion",
>   "prefill": {
>     "email":  'name@gmail.com',
>     "contact": '2323343423',
>   },          "offers":[
>           "offer_E1sqwDJweet2be",
>           "offer_E1s3stgErefovM"          ],
> }
> ```

On checkout I didn't found any offers drop down as per razorpay doc, please correct me if I am wrong

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. Create Offers from the Dashboard
2. [Create an Order](https://razorpay.com/docs/offers/integration/#step-1-order-creation) to pass the Offers in the Order request.
3. Obtain the `order_id` from Step 2.
4. Pass that `order_id` in your js code.

This should work!